# Unit test - not showing TEST_TARGET_NAME in Build Settings

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

Maybe I have never seen this but shouldn't Unit tests show a `TEST_TARGET_NAME` 
in build settings? I just added a Unit test target to an app that has Obj-C code mixed with Swift and I can't get the Unit test to run correctly. It crashes on run time. I have been looking at the build setting from unit tests to the UI test target that is already there and a few things come to mind. First, the non-existent test target name from build settings under User-Defined is not there and
 `Bundle Loader` 
has stuff inputted in it on the Unit test but not the UITest target and for some reason the 'Product Bundle Identifier' on the Unit test is different than on the UI test target. Also, 'Weak References in Manual Retain Release' is set to `YES` on UI but `NO` on Unit. `Test Host` is populated on Unit but not on UITest. Again the UI test target seems to run just fine but it doesn't reference any classes from the app. It literally just runs the UIApplication and does a run through the app. The Unit Test I get one main crash on run-time dealing with a 
`Thread 1: implicit Objective-C entrypoint +[<class name> UI] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4.`

I will say I picked up this project and trying to clean a lot of it up but I feel like the previous developers just started upgrading to the latest and greatest versions of Xcode and never really migrating cleanly. Can anyone provide any input on this?

Comment: OK - so I modified the Unit test build settings to match 'mostly' the UITest target build settings besides the `Product Bundled Identifier` and can get the Unit test to run but as soon as I put in the `@testable import <module name - app name>   

I can get the test to run that successfully but the kicker is when I add in a parameter to reference a class from the app such as doing something like this:  

`let ticket = <class name> () `  I get an linker error : `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Also seeing this above the linker error:    `type metadata accessor for <className.Class I'm referencing", referenced from: ` . then shows quite a few .o files   (sorry I can't show more info than this) but can provide as much information as I can

Comment: I had a similar issue. Setting the Test Target Name to none and back to the correct target name in the General tab fixed it for me.